# Catching JQuery Events in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there any tool which can help me catch the jQuery,JavaScript,Ajax events in browsers like chrome or firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has its debugger.
Firefox has firebug and its own built in developer tools.
Latest IE's have their own developer tools as well.

Every one of these tools has a built in `Network` tab which will tell you what XHR calls were made.

If you add breakpoints in your event handlers, from the afore mentioned developer tools for your browser, you should be able to debug from there.

[Chromes dev tools page](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) will get you started on this if you're using chrome!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean see all/any events firing, then Chrome can already do it.

Check the screenshot out, the panel will pause the script at whatever event you select... allowing you to debug it in the source/console panel

[image: Chrome Dev Tools / Event Listener]